# <Ruby> How can I convert "array in array" to "hash in array"? For examle, convert [["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I would like to convert each array in array like `[["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]` to hash in array such as [{"H", 3}, {"S", 3}, {"D", 3}, {"H", 10}, {"S", 4}].

This is a judgement service of Poker Hands, so same keys like H appear and I cant use `Hash[suit.zip num]`.

If using `Hash[suit.zip num]`, the result is `{"H"=>10, "S"=>4, "D"=>5, "C"=>5}`

Teach me how to solve this problem, please.

Comment: ```[{"H", 3}, {"S", 3}, {"D", 3}, {"H", 10}, {"S", 4}]``` is not a valid Ruby Hash.

Comment: BTW, there are hardly any benefits from using single-pair hashes over 2-element arrays. It’s probably more overhead.

Comment: oh, I see. I understood the correct way to use Ruby Hash. By thee way, is `[{suit: "H", num: 3}, {suit: "S", num: 4}, {suit: "D", num: 5}, {suit: "C", num: 5}, {suit: "H", num: 10}]` benefit? If benefit, could you tell me how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a pair (array of 2 elements) into a one-key hash, you have to

```rb
pair = ["A", 1]
h = Hash[*pair]  # This is just Hash["A", 1]
# => {"A" => 1}
```

now you have to map this over your original array

```rb
array = [["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]
ar_of_hashes = array.map { |pair| Hash[*pair] }
```

but take also in account that `map` and friends are able to "distribute" an item into arguments of a block, so this would also work:

```rb
array = [["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]
ar_of_hashes = array.map { |(letter, number)| {letter => number} }
```

this is actually taking a single parameter, that is an array of 2, and automatically taking out the items.

Finally, if a block has more than 1 argument, and the count of arguments matches the size of the iterated item as an array, then it is automatically distributed:

```rb
array = [["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]
ar_of_hashes = array.map { |letter, number| {letter => number} }
```

notice that now the block has 2 arguments instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [["H", 3], ["S", 3], ["D", 3], ["H", 10], ["S", 4]]
array.map { |item| [item].to_h }
# => [{"H"=>3}, {"S"=>3}, {"D"=>3}, {"H"=>10}, {"S"=>4}]
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.